# How fast do you upload large file with commons-fileupload

Tags: java, apache-commons-fileupload

I'm a beginner in Java, and I use the Apache's commons-fileupload and conmmons-io to upload large file.It took me 20 seconds to copy a file size of 40m using this code. Is this normal?I have found a lot of places without an answer,and I would be grateful for any help,Thanks.
This is an example of copying official code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemStream;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemIterator;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

public class UploadServlet2 extends HttpServlet {

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

}

@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
    try {
        FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(req);
        System.out.println("start....");
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            FileItemStream item = iter.next();
            String name = item.getFieldName();
            InputStream stream = item.openStream();
            if (item.isFormField()) {

            } else {
                String value = item.getName();
                int start = value.lastIndexOf("\\");
                String fileName = value.substring(start + 1);
                System.out.println(fileName);
                FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(stream, new File("C:/dest.exe"));
                long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("total seconds:" + (endTime - startTime) / 1000);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: where are you uploading that file? to a remote server or to  your local machine? maybe you have slow internet speed...

Comment: It was tested on my local machine.I used tomcat8.5 and JDK1.8.

Comment: It's a stupid question but, just to be sure. You know that 'System.out.println("total seconds:" + (endTime - startTime))' return the elapsed time in millisecods right? so if it is printing 20, it means 20 mills

Comment: sorry,I wrote it wrong. It prints more than 20,000 milliseconds.How long does this code take for you to run?I think should try it on other machines and see if it's my problem.

Comment: Is there a virus scanner running on the machine?